# Is it possible to use Custom EventArgs with SystemEvents?

Tags: c#, events

My first post, apologies if this has been answered already - I have searched and searched but have not found any specifics on using Custom EventArgs with existing SystemEvents.

I am trying to take advantage of the SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged type events but would like to use my own Custom EventArgs instead of the standard PowerModeChangedEventArgs.  My approach was to create a class called CustomPowerModeChangedEventArgs which inherits from PowerModeChangedEventArgs and use these instead but I don't know how to tell the PowerModeChangedEventHandler to use these new CustomEvent args.  My code is as follows:

```
   //Define the custom args which inherit from the PowerModeChangedEventArgs
    public class CustomPowerModeChangedEventArgs : PowerModeChangedEventArgs
    {
       public string batterylevel { get; set; }
    }

   //event raising method with CustomArgs instead of the PowerModeChangedEventArgs
    protected virtual void PowerModeChanged(object source, CustomPowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += new PowerModeChangedEventHandler(PowerModeChanged);
```

The problem is with the PowerModeEventChangedHandler not accepting the method PowerModeChanged with the CustomArgs.  Had it been a generic eventhandler I could define the args like...

```
public event EventHandler<CustomPowerModeChangedEventArgs> PowerModeCHanged;
```

...but I can't fathom how to achieve similar with a non generic event handler.  I have a suspicion that it might be possible to send the new custom args to the handler using lambda expressions but I'm really not sure about this - maybe I need to define a whole new EventChangedHandler?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't get to decide what parameters the event handler has. Bear in mind that there's already code in the system which is going to *call* your event handler... how would you expect it to construct an instance of your `CustomPowerModeChangedEventArgs`?

If the event had been declared using `EventHandler<T>`, that still wouldn't have helped you - the code calling the event handler has already been written, and it's going to pass in a [`PowerModeChangedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.powermodechangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) that *it* constructs, not an instance of your type.

Now you could declare your *own* event using your custom event-args, and then hook into the `SystemEvents` so that you raise your own event (with an instance of your own event-args, however you decide to construct that) when the system event is raised... but you shouldn't expect to be able to add an event handler which requires information the event raiser (in this case the system) isn't aware of.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you Jon Skeet.  Does this mean that In order to have events triggered on a system property change of some kind with Custom Args I will need to write a new class or use two events with one custom event in conjunction to the predefined PowerModeChanged event?

Comment: @Chi: Yes - basically think of it from the system's point of view. It knows how to raise events and construct its own event args. Only *your* code is going to create instances of *your* event args.

Comment: Thank you Jon Skeet, much obliged. Perfectly explained, I now feel I have some clarity on the matter.  Thanks for taking the time to impart your knowledge and thank heavens for the existence of stackoverflow.com.